# Adjusting the size of the UIImageView in a Right Detail style UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a simple application which contains a few `UITableViewControllers` in a `UITabBarController`. The last `UITableViewController` is called the `More` tab and it's a `static UITableView`. I have designed everything in `Storyboard`.

Within the `More UITableView`, I have 4 `sections`. Within section One, Two and Three, I have 2 `basic UITableViewCells`. That works well. Within section four, I have 11 `basic UITableViewCells`. I'm populating the `cell` titles within `Storyboard`. I have decided to slightly modify the UI so that section 4 contains a small image and the label.

To do this, I have used `Right Detail` as the style of the `UITableViewCell` because it allows you in the inspector, to specify an image.

[image]

The problem at the moment is that the image looks just too big. 
[image]

I have the image in the view, but the size inspector is greyed out.

[image]
Without using a custom `UITableViewCell` (because everything works in this way; just the image is too big), how can I specify the size of the `UIImageView`? And where do I specify that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a UITableViewCell subclass and set it to your static cell within storyboard, e.g.

```
@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell
@end

@implementation MyCell
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    //TODO: adjust self.imageView
    //self.imageView.contentMode = ...
    //self.imageView.frame = ...    
}

@end
```

Or, you can click on that imageView and change it's `Mode` to `Center` from the inspector and set an image with right sizes that you want to display.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out @artudev - just after posting the question, I tried that but I have some weird issues. I have a custom UITableViewCell subclass called MoreCustomTableViewCell and in Storyboard, I am assigning the UITableViewCell to use that class. However, when I try to create an IBOutlet for it, nothing happens - it doesn't drag to create that or right click to create the IBOutlet on the UIImageView. I've not had a problem before with a custom subclass, but then I've been using different tables, like dynamic styles.

Comment: There is no need to create an outlet for imageView, because UITabelViewCell already has that property, just use it :)

Comment: Ah man ! That's just perfect - thanks so much @artudev - I had no idea you could access that property! Thanks - works like a charm :)